# Datetimepicker help in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

Why this error occurs when i run the program :

> Value of '1/1/0001 7:34:00 PM' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'MinDate' and 'MaxDate'.

```
' i want to set my datetimepicker to my current system time
TimeDateTimePicker.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mmtt")
```

Comment: Then use `TimeDateTimePicker.Value = DateTime.Now` which is the same as if you don't set it at all. I would also suggest to set `OPTIION STRICT ON` to prevent silent casts which could be incorrect.

Comment: can work for that 1. However, now i want to disable people from changing the time and date.Me.Item_issuedTableAdapter.Insert(TimeDateTimePicker.Value, DateissueDateTimePicker.Value)...then insert into my table in database

Comment: but they insert the long date for my date field and 0:00am for my time field in database

Answer (score 0):

The error is self explanatory, see the [TimeDateTimePicker.MinDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.mindate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [TimeDateTimePicker.MaxDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.maxdate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) properties to know what years you can assing in a date.

Minimum Date:

> 1/1/1753 00:00:00

Maximum Date:

> 12/31/9998 23:59:59